# Button not updating its text

Tags: java, android

I'm working an android game. When the application start it show a button ("Start") to start the game. When the user lose, the application should show the original view and changing the button text to "Restart". When I start the application everything works fine but when the user lose I get the original view (button text not changed) and even the button not responding. I have two classes : GameActivity and GameView :
In GameActivity I have this :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init();
 }

public void init() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catch_game);
    fruitView = (CatchGameView) findViewById(R.id.l3InfoCatchGameView1);
    fruitView.setActivity(this);
    if (bStart == null) { //When we launch the app
        bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

        bStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonStartClickEventHandler();

            }

        });
    } else{
        bStart.setText("Restart"); 
    }

}
```

In GameView I have this :

```
private void showScore() {
    stopTimer();
    AlertDialog.Builder popupBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this.getContext());
    TextView message = new TextView(this.getContext());
    message.setText("Score : " + score);
    message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    popupBuilder.setView(message);
    popupBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    popupBuilder.setNeutralButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    invalidate();
                    activity.init();
                }
            });
    popupBuilder.show();

}
```

When I debug I see that the instruction that change the button text is executed. Thanks for your help

Comment: what do you mean  user lose ?

Comment: When the game finish. My game finish when the user lose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `init()` method calls `setContentView()`.

When you do this, the Activity's layout is re-inflated. All of your references to Views (such as `bstart`) now point to Views in the old copy of the layout, which is now no longer visible to the user.

Since `bstart` is still referencing something though,  `if (bStart == null)` is false and you don't get an updated reference to `bstart`.

I would move separate your logic for updating the button's text from your logic for setting up your Activity's layout.

Answer (score 0):

move the setContentView to onCreate. since when you call activity.init();, your setting the view again

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_catch_game);
  init();
}
```

Comment: But like this the start button is not showing because I have removed it when I started the game

Comment: Are you actually removing it, or are you calling [`setVisibility(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))? The latter will allow you to re-show it later.

Comment: you have to hide the button using bStart.setVisibility(View.GONE)